# ASPX - FindControl(string) finding control but not its value

Tags: c#, asp.net, dynamic

I am having trouble with my ASPX page. Based on a selection from a listbox, the website (dynamically) generates the appropriate controls.

Later in a `ButtonClick` event, I need to get the text values of several textboxes. Here's the problem, the code I have recognizes the textboxes with their appropriate properties (like ID) but *not* their `Text` values.

Here is the code I use:

```
//This is part of the company framework and is merely to provide context. 
Dal.Customer newCus = new Dal.Customer();

//It recognizes the textboxes, but doesn't find the text inside it. (there is text in the textboxes)
TextBox txtCusName = (TextBox)Page.FindControl("ctl00$ContentPlaceHolder1$txtCusName");
TextBox txtCusCode = (TextBox)Page.FindControl("ctl00$ContentPlaceHolder1$txtCusCode");

newCus.DisplayName = txtCusName.Text;
newCus.CustomerCode = txtCusCode.Text;
```

I wish to know what I am doing wrong here and what steps I am missing, or if there is another (better) way to get what I need.

Thanks in advance.

**EDIT**

Per request, here is the code that 'generates' (or better said  'writes') the appropriate controls on the page after a selection has been made from the Listbox.

```
private void CreateCustomerTemplate(Control control)
    {
        PlaceHolder ph = new PlaceHolder();

        TextBox txtCusName = new TextBox();
        TextBox txtCusCode = new TextBox();

        txtCusName.ClientIDMode = ClientIDMode.Static;
        txtCusCode.ClientIDMode = ClientIDMode.Static;

        txtCusName.ID = "txtCusName";
        txtCusCode.ID = "txtCusCode";
        ph.Controls.Add(new LiteralControl("<table><tr><td>" +
                "Customer Name: </td><td>"));
        ph.Controls.Add(txtCusName);
        ph.Controls.Add(new LiteralControl("</td></tr><tr><td>" +
                "Customer Code: </td><td>"));
        ph.Controls.Add(txtCusCode);
        ph.Controls.Add(new LiteralControl("</td></tr>"));

        ph.Controls.Add(new LiteralControl("</table>"));

        control.Controls.Add(ph);

    }
```

And here is the code that takes the selection of the ListBox and ultimately calls the creation of the appropriate controls. This happens in the `SelectedIndexChanged`-event (with `AutoPostBack=true`).

```
switch (ddlType.SelectedItem.Value)
        {
            case "null":
                btnSend.Visible = false;
                break;

            case "Customer":
                new Template(TemplateType.Customer, spantempcontent);
                btnSend.Visible = true;
                templateType = TemplateType.Customer;
                break; 
                //The switch goes on
         }
```

Comment: Try `txtCusName.Value.ToString()`.

Comment: _"doesn't find the text inside it"_ means `txtCusName.Text` returns `""`? I suspect you are recreating the textboxes too late. Do it in `Page_Init`

Comment: txtCusName.Value is not usable here because the textbox is an ASPX control. Were it an HTML control this would have worked. But thanks for trying. @AshishSrivastava

Comment: Exactly, it returns `""`, it returns an empty string while there is clearly text inside the controls. @TimSchmelter

Comment: @SHW: have you read my second sentence? Show the code. You have to recreate dynamic controls on every postback

Comment: @TimSchmelter is most likely on the right track here. If the controls are added dynamically, they need to be re-added in the postback before the `HttpApplication.AcquireRequestState` event is triggered. That means they should be created in (for instance) the `Page_Init` event... In order to give help here, we need to see how you add and re-add these controls.

Comment: @user1429080 Oh, so when the choice in the listbox is made and the controls are added to the page, I also need to add them to the PostBack? And I will share the code that renders the controls is a minute.

Answer (score 1):

You are trying to find the elements by their ID given to Controls in the HTML while you should be using the asp.net ID.

So change

```
TextBox txtCusName = (TextBox)Page.FindControl("ctl00$ContentPlaceHolder1$txtCusName");
```

Into

```
TextBox txtCusName = (TextBox)Page.FindControl("txtCusName");
```

asp.net changes the ID's of Controls inside Placeholders, data repeating Controls (GridView, Repeater) to this `ctl00$ContentPlaceHolder1$txtCusName` to ensure there will be no duplicate ID's at the client side.

**UPDATE**

You always need to recursively find the Controls. So if you use Master Pages you need to find the ContentPlaceHolder first.

```
ContentPlaceHolder cph = Master.FindControl("ContentPlaceHolder1") as ContentPlaceHolder;
TextBox tb = cph.FindControl("txtCusName") as TextBox;
```

Is the TextBox located in another Control like a Panel, then you need to find the Panel and then the TextBox.

```
ContentPlaceHolder cph = Master.FindControl("ContentPlaceHolder1") as ContentPlaceHolder;
Panel p = cph.FindControl("Panel1") as Panel;
TextBox tb1 = p.FindControl("txtCusName") as TextBox;
```

Comment: Using the ID is the first thing I tried. But if I use the ID the entire thing returns `null`.

Comment: Where are you trying to find the Control? From the Master Page or the aspx page?

Comment: I am trying to find the control that is in my aspx page itself. I had it in a `<span>` at first. But I ran into the same problem. When I used the span, I had `spanId.FindControl("txtCusName");`.

Comment: Updated my answer.